# Permission Denied when installing pip with get-pip.py

Tags: python, windows, pip

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
Python: 3.7.4

When I install pip with any methods below:

Online installation:

```
python get-pip.py
```

User Installation:

```
python get-pip.py --user
```

Offline Installation: (with pip and wheel packages placed in 'd:\python374\packages')

```
python get-pip.py --no-index --find-links=d:\python374\packages
```

All return the same permission denied error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-8ecxsaac\\pip\\pip/_vendor/distlib/w64.exe'
Check the permissions.
```

I have already used the administrator account to install the pip.

Any ideas to fix the issue?

Comment: `python3.7` should come with a `pip` module. You don't need to install `pip` again. Could you try, `py3 -m pip --version` and report back ?

Comment: Please see this [section](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel) if you have multiple `python`s installed

Comment: `no module named pip` when I run the `py3 -m pip --version`, and I encountered the same permission denied error when I run `python -m ensurepip --default-pip`

Comment: It works after I copying the whole 'pip' and 'pip-19..2.2.dist-info' folders from my colleague's computer to 'D:\Python374\Lib\site-packages\' in my computer. Tested installing something and it works. Thanks.